# Hive Merge command is not working in Spark HiveContext

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, acid, hivecontext

I am running hive merge command using Spark HiveContext in 1.6.3 spark version, but it is failing with below error.

```
2017-09-11 18:30:33 Driver [INFO ] ParseDriver - Parse Completed
2017-09-11 18:30:34 Driver [INFO ] ParseDriver - Parsing command: MERGE INTO emp_with_orc AS T USING SOURCE_TABLE AS S 
ON T.id = S.id 
WHEN MATCHED AND (S.operation = 1) THEN UPDATE SET a = S.a,b = S.b 
WHEN MATCHED AND (S.operation = 2) THEN DELETE 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (S.id, S.a, S.b)
2017-09-11 18:30:34 Driver [ERROR] HiveWriter - Error while executing the merge query.
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near 'MERGE' 'INTO' 'emp_with_orc'; line 1 pos 0
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.createPlan(HiveQl.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:40)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:135)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:202)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
```

I am not sure if ACID transaction merge command is supported or not in HiveContext of spark.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To use `MERGE` operation you will need to execute it through the HIVE JDBC since MERGE is not supported by Spark SQL as of this day.

Answer (score 1):

Spark doesn't support `UPDATES` or `DELETES` so exception is an expected behavior.